# problem building freenect_stack

Tags: ros, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I've downloaded the freenect_stack, although I've getting the following error using rosmake on the stack:

```
MSG: gencfg_cpp on:Test.cfg CMake Error at cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:66 (string): string sub-command REPLACE requires at least four arguments. Call Stack (most recent call first): cmake/cfgbuild.cmake:87 (gencfg_cpp) CMakeLists.txt:24 (include) when rosmake
```

I've looked around to see if there is something I need to update - not found anthing that stands out. Rest of my ros system is working/building with out issue.

Any insight would be most helpful

This is on debian with furte

Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49100/problem-building--freenect_stack/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2012-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Something is not correct while generating the dynamic reconfigure config file. Can you post the output of the following command:

```
roscd freenect_camera
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure gendeps cfg/Freenect.cfg
```

You might also want to refer to this ticket: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4234

---

Originally posted by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) with karma: 2871 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0